I cant manage to track Single Page Apps (Angular) with Google Tag Manager
Hi I have setup Google Tag Manager and added the script in the index file following the instructions and I added the AngulariticsModule, Angularitics2GoogleTagManager.
But when I go to Google Tag Manager and view Realtime Overview. I can see that it works up correctly showing the current page that the user is in but when I go to a different page it doesn't update the activePage. but under the activatedPage I see an event coming in for the pageview with the new page that I just went to and even the history because I added some tags.
However the only way I found to change the ActivaPage is to Refresh the page.
you can see in this picture that I initiated the page in the appointments but even if I changed it and I did get the page view and history saying that I changed the page but the active page still says appointments

this is a picture of the history:

I am using: @angular/cli 17.3.8

can you show the actual dimension that's being sent that has the old page name? As long as document.location data is updated on your navigations, you should be ok.

@BNazaruk thx for the response, did you mean history? if yes I just added it

so seems to me like the new url is determined correctly? What's the problem then?

@BNazaruk but the current page (activepage ) in google tags manager didn't change isn't that important??

unless you can see it out of place in the network call, it's not worth mentioning.
